# Setup Nagios to monitor custom SQL query

Tags: sql, monitoring, nagios

I have Nagios (and nagiosql installed to help me out) but I'm a bit of a beginner and not sure what to do so here is my question:

How do I setup monitoring of a specific SQL query in Oracle Database using Nagios?

Example:

Table in Oracle contains only 1 row with 2 columns:

RUN_STAT | LAST_EXEC_TIMESTAMP

I wish to setup Nagios to execute SQL query on this table and return difference between current time and LAST_EXEC_TIMESTAMP in seconds. 
If result at the time of execution is more than n seconds return critical, otherwise return OK.

How do I do that?

I already did the SQL part but I'm not sure how to pass it to Nagios - which plugin to use and how to handle output value :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a standard plugin called "check_oracle" that might help you, and there are also a handful of Oracle-specific plugins on [Nagios Exchange](http://exchange.nagios.org/directory/Plugins/Databases/Oracle).

At first glance, it doesn't look like the stock check_oracle plugin allows you to run specific queries, but I'm not 100% sure as I've never used it.

Consol Labs also maintains a collection of "check_(db)_health" plugins that are quite excellent, and they have [an Oracle-specific one](http://labs.consol.de/lang/en/nagios/check_oracle_health/). **You can use "--mode sql" to run your own queries.**

To use any of these, you must have the Oracle client set up already, and the proper ENV vars set, to connect to the Oracle DB.

If you can't connect directly to the Oracle DB from your Nagios box, your other option is to use NRPE/check_by_ssh to run a plugin locally, on the Oracle DB server itself.